# Javascript - Creating new div with form select onChange

Tags: javascript, html

I am having difficulty trying to create a new div using javascript from a form. 
I have a select box in my html form;

```
<select name="seasonSelector" id="seasonSelector" onchange="jsSeason('seasonWrapper')">
```

My seasonWrapper is a div which contains the whole content and onChange I am using a Javascript function to create a new div but having difficulty.

```
function jsSeason(divname) { 
    var x = document.getElementById('seasonSelector');
    if(x = 2) { 
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
        document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(newDiv); 
    }
}
```

Not really sure what it is i'm doing wrong or not including in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is select element, you want yo read its value:

```
if (x.value == 2) {
    // ...
}
```

Also note, that you should use comparison operator `==` instead of assignment `=`.